# Creating a spinning pie chart (wheel) android

Tags: android, android-animation, spinning

I have created an Pie chart which I want to spin randomly and stop on click.
Then my android program needs to read which value is above.

I already got this:

```
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, "");

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(false);
    pieChart.animateXY(1400, 1400);

    pieChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false);
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    xVals.add("Correct");
    xVals.add("Wrong");
    colors.add(Color.rgb(115, 255, 134));
    colors.add(Color.rgb(255, 115, 115));
    dataSet.setColors(colors);
    pieChart.setDescription("");

    PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);

    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    data.setValueTextSize(18f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    pieChart.setData(data);
    pieChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            pieChart.spin( 500,0,-360f, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad);
        }
    });
```

I don't know how to spin this chart on click and stop it randomly.
Then I need to get the value of the chart which is spinned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library.
**(Easy and simple implementation of PieChart with Scatter)**
This library will fulfill all the requirements you have mentioned above.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4492

Comment: Thanks, but how do I let it spin and read the value that is spinned?

Comment: i think you can use setOnTouchListener . Implement this and i am sure you will figure out something.Go though this library and its code.There must be something to implement it.

Comment: Oke ill try, will ask for your help if I cannot get it work!

Comment: How can I get the value of the spinned chart??